# How to modify remote history with git filter-repo?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

In the past I've used `git filter-branch` to remove files from my git history. Following that, I can do a force push to update the remote repository. For example, removing all HTML files from the local repo and then rewriting the remote to reflect the change:

```
$ git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r \*.html' --prune-empty -- --all
$ git push origin --force --all
```

This works perfectly fine. But seeing as `filter-branch` is extremely slow and has been deprecated for a while, I'd like to do this with `git-filter-repo` instead. So far, this seems to be the equivalent command:

```
$ git-filter-repo --force --path-glob *.html --invert-paths
```

This first step appears to work. My issue is when I attempt a force push afterwards, I see my remotes have been lost.

```
$ git push origin --force --all
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The filter-repo command appears to have removed my remote URLs when I check `git remote -v`. Adding back the remote manually puts me down a rabbit hole of other settings be invalid.

**Why does `git-filter-repo` remove my remote? And how can I rewrite remote's history using `git-filter-repo` like I'm able to with `git filter-branch`?**

Comment: For those with similar issues, it may be relevant to backup the remote URL configuration in _.git/config_ at somewhere else before `git filter-repo`, for later restoration. This is mentioned in the Github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why does git-filter-repo remove my remote?

[The documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) explains their reasoning, in the section titled [INTERNALS](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#INTERNALS):

> 3. We don’t want users accidentally pushing back to the original repo, as discussed in [DISCUSSION](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#DISCUSSION). It also reminds users that since history has been rewritten, this repo is no longer compatible with the original. Finally, another minor benefit is this allows users to push with the `--mirror` option to their new home without accidentally sending remote tracking branches.

> And how can I rewrite remote's history using git-filter-repo like I'm able to with git filter-branch?

Just use `git remote add` to put `origin` back, or—since step 3 in the command sequence is `git remote rm origin`—just *rename* `origin` to some other name first.  If you do that, though, note step 2.

You said:

> Adding back the remote manually puts me down a rabbit hole of other settings be invalid.

You'll need to go into more detail here, obviously.

Comment: but how do I rewrite the history of the remote repo, by also deleting files in the remote repo, such as done in the local repo? My remote repo increased in size, after this, did not decrease

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: the *designed usage* for `git filter-repo` is that you *archive the old repository and create a new one*. You don't update the original.  If you do want to update the original, you must understand Git deeply. (In short: don't update the original after filtering unless you know what you're doing.)

Comment: I understood that, that's why you lose the git config file. But eventually you do that because you want to save space at the remote repo, by replacing the new local repo by the old remote one. How do you do that?

Comment: Depends on the remote. On a corporate server I'd move the old repository to some archival backup storage (maybe on S3?) and create a new one for the new repo. On GitHub, not sure what I'd do.

Comment: I mean exactly Github :)

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: OK: note that GItHub never delete any *commits* from any existing repository (for GitHub-internal reasons). So if the old repo *on* GitHub isn't explicitly removed *from* GitHub, all those commits remain there, using up space. Whether that's a problem (and for whom) might affect your approach. It's probably worth getting in touch with GitHub support to get *their* advice.

Answer (score -1):

working on git recently.
got the same issue.

after running git-filter-repo, my "git branch -r" returns nothing.
To get the output back,
you need:

```
git remote add origin xxxxxxxxxxx
git fetch --all
```

Then, you will get your "git branch -r" output back.