# Why isn't git clone setting up a remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

On a new laptop running Git 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128), I notice that whenever I clone a repo, I don't get a remote (and hence remote tracking branch) setup:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com/myuser/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 70, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 34), reused 63 (delta 27), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (70/70), 180.33 KiB | 124.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (34/34), done.
$ cd myproject
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git remote -vv
$
$ git branch -a
* master
$ ls -l .git/refs
total 0
...redacted... heads
...redacted... remotes
...redacted... replace
...redacted... tags
$ ls -l .git/refs/remotes
$
```

Is there some setting somewhere I need to change? It's a bit tedious having to manually create a remote each time when I always want to push back from where I cloned.

The documentation clearly says this should be happening:

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch -r), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository's currently active branch.

I'm getting the active branch checked out, but no remote.

Comment: What do you get from `git branch -a`? How about `ls -l .git/refs` and `ls -l .git/refs/remotes`?

Comment: Added all those to the question - short answer, really no remotes or branches other than local master.

Comment: Weird. I don't know of a config option that would do that, but check if `git config -l --show-origin` has anything funny. Could be a bug, try a different Git.

Comment: I still feel like either you’re not where you think or you are doing something you are not mentioning. I would expect this sort of thing after `git init`, not `git clone`.

Comment: That's very weird. Git is acquiring a new configuration setting for the default name of the remote (was hardwired to `origin` unless overridden at `git clone` time, soon to be from a config entry) but I don't think this was added to Apple-Git yet. (Even if it were, that would at worst change the name from `origin` to whatever you or Apple had configured.)

Comment: @torek Experimentally I tried setting that option to an empty string but that just caused an error while cloning. I don’t think it lets you eradicate the remote altogether. It’s more like something comes along and deletes the remote after the clone.

Comment: Another strange thingis that a regular `git clone` does not clone the `refs/replace` hierarchy, yet, your output shows that there are or have been replacement objects.

Comment: Ok, this is strange - it has stopped happening. I don't know why. Between when I raised this question, and now, I was rewriting some history on a few repos, to correct my email address.  Each time I had to clone, run the script to replace emails, add remote, set upstream, force-push. Now when I clone, I do get the origin set up.

Comment: @matt I can see from my command history that the "you're not where you think you are" or "you didn't git clone" hypotheses aren't correct. Consecutive commands were: `git clone git@github.com:stevage/mapbox-gl-utils.git`, `cd mapbox-gl-utils`, `git-filter-repo ...`, then adding remote and force-pushing.

Comment: Hi @SteveBennett - well, this is the first time you've mentioned `git-filter-repo`. That might very well remove your remote! See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373656/how-to-modify-remote-history-with-git-filter-repo

Comment: By the way, now that you've told us what repo this is, I tried it myself: `git clone git@github.com:stevage/mapbox-gl-utils.git; cd mapbox-gl-utils; git remote -vv`. There is definitely an `origin` here, and I don't know how you'd remove it without actually saying `git remote remove origin` directly or indirectly (e.g. thru `filter-repo`).

Comment: Fwiw, it wasn't just this one repo - I was doing this process on about 5-6.

Comment: Yes but every single instance of the "process" must have involved `filter-repo`. So that common feature was important to mention.

Comment: Dude. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your criticism, but it just seems unnecessary. Obviously I understand *with hindsight* that that was an important detail. If I had realised it at the time, I probably wouldn't have ended up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem turns out to be that you are using `git filter-repo`. That can indeed remove your remote (as discussed, for example, here: [How to modify remote history with git filter-repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373656/how-to-modify-remote-history-with-git-filter-repo)).

Comment: Ahhh. Sorry - I guess there's always a dangerous potential overlap between "removing irrelevant details" and "removing the only details that actually matter".

Comment: I have to say, I don't really buy their arguments. Plenty of Git commands rewrite history (notably, rebase, which is used all the time) - and they don't wipe out your remotes.

Comment: @SteveBennett Agreed, wow. Silent, surprising, presumptive, destructive training wheels. Hope the person who ran filter-repo remembered origin's URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would try first:

- to remove the global configuration `~/.gitconfig` (check with `git config -l --show-origin` if there are any other location to purge)
- to [upgrade Git](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272220) to the latest 2.31
- to clone again

That way, you can check if the issue persists with a recent Git and a clean configuration.

Comment: Yes but lots of other people use the same version of Git and don’t have this issue.

Comment: @matt Then at least resetting the global config is a good first step, in order to rule out any side-effect from the current one.

Comment: Agreed, hence the request to see `git config -l --show-origin`... Though what config could do this is unclear.

Comment: Currently my global config is just showing credential.helper=osxkeychain, and my user.name and user.email. However, given that the problem has stopped occurring now, and I had run `git-config user.email ...` that may not tell much.